# Insert new column into sql view

Tags: mysql, sql

Can i add new column into sql view and update that column with new data?

Comment: you cannot update data using a `view`, it is named `view` for a reason.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? But in general the answer is: no, you don't add a column to a view and update it. You add a column to a _table_ and update it. Then you need to re-create the view to include the new column

Comment: Please tell me whichone mysql, sqlserver, postgresql,oracle etc...?

Comment: mysql .i need to update a joined table when i update 2 tables that i have used to create that joined table

Comment: @rcs, some views are updatable, e.g. select * from table.

Comment: @jarlh it's changing the view schema, but does not update the data inside the table

Comment: @rcs, create table t(c integer); create view v as select c from t; insert into v values (13); select * from v;

Comment: @jarlh Ok, you are right in the example you've given. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

Actually View is nothing, it's a virtual existent of table. If you are updating the data, it mean you are updating in corresponding tables.

A view can be used in a query that updates data, subject to a few restrictions. Bear in mind that a view is not a table and contains no data—the actual modification always takes place at the table level. Views cannot be used as a mechanism to override any constraints, rules, or referential integrity defined in the base tables.

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW [Current Product List] AS
> SELECT ProductID,ProductName,Category
> FROM Products
> WHERE Discontinued=No
> ```

You can refer following article for more info.

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=130855&seqNum=4

hope this will help you.
thanks